# Java How do you declare a generic parameter to be any interface

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to learn some reflection in Java and I've run into a snag. Essentially I'm trying to create a really generic event system. Yes I know there are already many out there but this is more of an exercise in learning than anything practical. Anyway, I keep getting the following error when I declare an Instance of `EventSource<PersonnameChangeListener, PersonNameChangeEvent>`

```
error: type argument PersonNameChangeListener is not within bounds of type-variable ListenerT
    private EventSource<PersonNameChangeListener,
  where ListenerT is a type-variable:
    ListenerT extends Class declared in class EventSource
```

So My question is, "How do I declare that I want a generic parameter to be **any** interface?"

Thank you in advance,

Jec

```
public interface PersonNameChangeListener extends EventListener
{
    public void nameChangeOccured(PersonNameChangeEvent event);
}

public class PersonNameChangeEvent extends EventObject
{
    private String m_OldName;
    private String m_NewName;

    public PersonNameChangeEvent(Object source,
                                    String oldName,
                                    String newName)
    {
        super(source);

        m_OldName = oldName;
        m_NewName = newName;
    }

    public String getOldName()
    {
        return m_OldName;
    }

    public String getNewName()
    {
        return m_NewName;
    }
}

public class EventSource<ListenerT extends Class, EventT>
{
    List<ListenerT> m_ListenerList;

    public EventSource()
    {
        m_ListenerList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNameChangeListener(ListenerT listener)
    {
        m_ListenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeNameChangeListener(ListenerT listener)
    {
        m_ListenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    private void fireNameChangedEvent(EventT event) throws IllegalAccessException,
                                                              InvocationTargetException
    {
        for (ListenerT listener : m_ListenerList)
        {
             Method[] methods = listener.getDeclaredMethods();
             for (Method method : methods)
             {
                 Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
                 final int parameterCount = method.getParameterCount();
                 if (parameterCount == 1
                     && parameterTypes[1].getTypeName().compareTo(event.getClass().getTypeName()) == 0)
                 {
                     try
                     {
                        method.invoke(this, event);
                     }
                     catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e)
                     {
                         throw e;
                     }
                     break;
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EventSource<ListenerT extends Object>

Comment: I don't think you can, but why do you want to? This looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243725).

Comment: Unbounded type parameters can take any subtype of `Object` by default. Just remove `extends Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no value in declaring `ListenerT` to be a generic type parameter if you're going to have to reflect on it anyway to get the methods you need. I would remove the type parameter entirely and just use `Object`.

**Important note**: Doing it this way only makes sense for learning the reflection API, not for doing this in production. I realize you said that, but I wanted to reemphasize the point.

Comment: Thanks. Yea I plan on doing a profile on reflection vs non so I understand the costs better.

Comment: @jecjackal What I meant was, the right way to do it was to have the generic type parameter restrict which interface `ListenerT` can implement so you can just call `listener.theMethod()` because the type parameter ensures that method exists.